# Laravel Relationship Without Timestamps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there away to call a model with a relationship without timestamps when calling the with statement in the model itself - instead of going into that relationship model and saying $protected timestamps  = false;

e.g

```
class Post Extends Eloquent {       
    public function template() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Template', 'id', 'template_id')->timestamps(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The one way to do this would be to build the ``SELECT .. JOIN ...`` query using the Query Builder and then create Models from the results. It'd be a lot easier to just include the timestamps with the models.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in following model to skip the values

```
protected $hidden = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```